# External javascript character encoding on Webshpere

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, websphere

How can one set character encoding on external JavaScript files using only Websphere (5.1)? I don't have Apache in front of it so I can't set it using "AddCharset UTF-8 .js".

Or maybe there is some other way to force it on a web container via web.xml or similar magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/j2ee/encoding.jsp

You could also serve the JavaScript file through a servlet.